How to delete one of several images in the preview in input
How can I make it possible to delete 1 image from the 5 sent to the input? That's how I added a preview of the attached images to the input file
                <script>
                window.onload = function() {
  if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
    var filesInput = document.getElementById("file");
    filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      var files = event.target.files;
      var output = document.getElementById("result");
      for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        var file = files[i];
        if (!file.type.match('image'))
          continue;
        var picReader = new FileReader();
        picReader.addEventListener("load", function(event) {
          var picFile = event.target;
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.innerHTML = "<img class='thumbnail' src='" + picFile.result + "'" +
            "title='" + picFile.name + "'/>";
          output.insertBefore(div, null);
        });        
        picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
      }

    });
  }
}               
        </script>

<div><input style=" border: solid 1px #2a2f40; padding: 10px; width: auto; margin: 5px 0;" type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="multiple"  accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" onchange="loadFile(event)" ><legend style="font-size:10px;">(jpg, jpeg, png) Max file size: 15 MB.</legend></p>
                <div id="result" class="uploadPreview"></div></div>



To enable deletion of individual images from a preview in an HTML file input, you can add a delete button to each image preview and handle the deletion with JavaScript. Here's a simplified version of your script with the necessary modifications:
HTML
No changes needed in your HTML structure.
JavaScript
Add this updated script to handle file input changes and image deletions:


window.onload = function() {
    if (window.File && window.FileList && window.FileReader) {
        var filesInput = document.getElementById("file");
        filesInput.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            var output = document.getElementById("result");
            output.innerHTML = ''; // Clear the output to avoid duplicating images

            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                var file = files[i];
                if (!file.type.match('image')) continue;
                var picReader = new FileReader();

                picReader.onload = (function(file) {
                    return function(event) {
                        var div = document.createElement("div");
                        div.innerHTML = `<img class='thumbnail' src='${event.target.result}' title='${escape(file.name)}'/>
                                         <button onclick='this.parentNode.remove()'>X</button>`;
                        output.appendChild(div);
                    };
                })(file);

                picReader.readAsDataURL(file);
            }
        });
    }
};
<div>
  <input style="border: solid 1px #2a2f40; padding: 10px; width: auto; margin: 5px 0;" type="file" name="file[]" id="file" multiple="multiple" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png">
  <legend style="font-size:10px;">(jpg, jpeg, png) Max file size: 15 MB.</legend>
  <div id="result" class="upload Preview"></div>
</div>



Explanation

Clears the output div to avoid duplicating previews when adding new files.
Each image preview includes a delete button (X). Clicking this button removes the image preview from the DOM.

This script sets up each image with a delete button that, when clicked, will remove the image preview from the page.

Note that @Waseem also removed the onchange="loadFile(event)" from the original html, since loadFile() does not exist and the event listener is setup by the Javascript code.

Waseem Usman, as I understand it, it just deletes the images, but does not clear the input, when sending the form, the images are sent and uploaded
